# Assign command to the central soft button within javaMe

Tags: command, java-me, midlet

I have the mobile javaMe application that has been working on Nokia Phones. However, now I'm porting it to Samsung 5611, and I've faced with such a problem: no command is assigned on the central soft button, all of them are contained in the right-button menu. When the same midlet was launched on Nokia 3110c, one command was placed on central button, other ones (if >=2) were grouped into the options menu.
I tried Item.setDefaultCommand (no effect) and Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true) (such method not supported in SDK 3.4). Also I tried to change the type of one command to Ok or Screen, and change the priority, everything is without success.

Thanks in advance. Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there's no way for the developer to decide exactly on which softbuttons the commands belong. It is the individual device that decides. Some devices has two softbuttons, and some has three.
You can fiddle a bit with priorities, but you still can't force commands to specific softbuttons.
That's high-level GUI (Form) for you.

If you want to have control of such things, you need to go with low-level GUI (Canvas / GameCanvas). Nowadays there are several APIs you can use to create Form-like low-level GUI. Check out LWUIT for example, which I imagine makes it easy for you to port your high-level code into low-level.

But even when using low-level coding, you have to be aware of different devices having different keycodes for the softbuttons.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr Lou, for a quick reply. I wouldn't like to tell the device what button to assign. However, it seems that something in my application prohibits the device to use the central button at all. On the other hand, I see that sometimes the device use central button (e.g. when navigating its menu). I've read something at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227577/central-button-soft-key-lwuit, but I now see that it needs LWUIT